Selenium Python ошибка при подключении proxy ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Всем добрый день! пишу небольшой selenium скрипт на python с использованием своего прокси (покупал на proxy6) прокси рабочий, при проверке на httpbin.org/ip ip адрес успешно изменяется. Хочу использовать прокси на сайте https://prenotami.esteri.it/, но сайт с использованием этого прокси не открывается и выдаёт ошибку ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
Помогите пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина. Перепробовал уже все возможные варианты и все библиотеки для прокси что есть в интернете. Так же перепробовал три прокси разных стран (белорусия, сша, узбекистан) толку нету никакого, сайт так же не грузится, хотя другие сайты для проверки ip загружаются успешно и ip изменяется.
Вот мой код
import zipfile
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROXY_HOST = 'host'  # rotating proxy or host
PROXY_PORT = 8000 # port
PROXY_USER = 'user' # username
PROXY_PASS = 'pass' # password

manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)

def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(executable_path=r'path to driver'),
        options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    #driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address')
    driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    time.sleep(500)
main()```


